# What are the details of using answers in your code?

Tags: discussion, creative-commons

At the bottom of stack overflow it says "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required". The Creative Commons license states that "You are free to remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially as long as you follow the license terms"

First of all, is it to the website or to the user that I make my attribution when distributing code?

Second of all, this wording leads me to believe that I am obligated to credit a party if I use their answer in any way. Does this go down to the concept? If someone teaches me how to do something in a language, in which of the following circumstances am I obligated to credit them?

- I copy and paste their code somewhere
- I type their code somewhere
- I copy and paste their code somewhere and edit it
- I use the concepts detailed in their answer somewhere
- I use the knowledge detailed in their answer that I have retained in a circumstance not mentioned in or related to the answered question
- I teach someone else how to do that same thing in another medium

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Credit would go to the author, not the site.  Users keep ownership of their own posts.  Copying or typing makes no difference.  Editing it would be a derivative work and still counts as copying.  As copyright only covers the exact expression of a creative work, using the concepts or knowledge without attribution is OK (and the same with teaching).

As for when you need to attribute…technically, if you copy so much as one line, you need to give credit.  This is why [one shouldn't use CC licenses for code](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F), it makes no sense.  They should have made it public domain or BSD or CC without attribute.  But at any rate, legally you have to give credit if you copy anything.  Whether you'd have to in a compiled version is something you could argue in court—it could be viewed as a derivative work or as a new expression.  Attribution checked into the file it resides in may be legally enough.

In reality, nobody is going to sue for anything they posted here.  I wouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: There are such things as fair-use and copyrightability. Both concepts restrict copyright.

Comment: True, but the larger code samples here (probably not the 4-5 liners) are copyrightable.  As for fair use-  if you're writing academic code, you probably qualify. If you're using a snippet, you qualify.  If someone posts a 300 line file and you copy it, you don't.  But that kind of stuff gets into fuzzy areas.  For myself, I consider anything I've posted here to be public domain.

Comment: It also depends on where the author and the copier live.  Copyright laws are not the same world wide (for example some countries don't have fair use).  If you're truly worried, contact an attorney who knows your local laws.

Comment: If someone posts a 300 line file, something aside from copyrights has probably gone wrong.

Comment: *Credit would go to the author, not the site* - what about posts that have been converted to *Community Wiki*?

Comment: Also, please note that the definitions and practice of "fair use" vary from one legislation to another. IMHO, if I post a snippet onto this site, it may be used and abused any way possible as long as nobody claims it is my work after it has been abused. I am fully aware of the fact that my possibilities to control what has left my keyboard are essentially nil.

Comment: Another related IP rights question is patentability of ideas presented here. With a slight exception it is clear that if there is a SO post describing an idea (question, answer, comment), it will prevent patenting that idea after the post has been published. The slight exception is the US with the FITF system and the grace period - that may or may not change the situation. (Personally, I think software patents are evil, but if you plan to patent an idea, be very careful with what you publish here.)